# Application.Run working for one workbook but not another

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a Workbook that has a bunch of data on it, and any new data has to be put on one of two different Workbooks (2015 and 2016). I've written a macro on the main Workbook that decides which of the two target Workbooks each piece of new data needs to go to, and it writes the data down on a blank sheet on the target Workbook.

Now, for 2015 and 2016 I've written a macro that does exactly what I want it to do, and the code is EXACTLY the same (as it should be), but when I try and call that macro from the main Workbook it only works for 2016, not 2015.

The method I'm using to run the macro from the main Workbook is:

```
Application.Run ("'2015.xlsm'!MAIN")
```

Where `MAIN` is the name of the macro on both of the target workbooks, as shown below.

```
Global WS As Worksheet, NS As Worksheet

Sub MAIN()

    Set WS = Sheets(55)
    Set NS = Sheets(56)

    NS.Cells.Clear

    Dim n As Integer
    n = WS.Cells(60000, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Number of orders to add/change

    If n = 0 Then Exit Sub

    CleanUp (n)
    AddOrders (n)
    UpdateChassis (n)

    WS.Cells.Clear

End Sub
```

`CleanUp`, `AddOrders` and `UpdateChassis` are all just other subs.

Running `MAIN` manually on the 2015 sheet works fine, just not when you call it from the main Workbook.

Can anybody explain to me why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Comment: From where you are calling your Main sub to run, I mean where have you kept the line `Application.Run ("'2015.xlsm'!MAIN")`?

Comment: The main sub of the main Workbook. This shouldn't be the issue though because it works perfectly with the 2016 file...

Comment: When you say its not working from 2015, is it giving you any error or something?

Comment: Your problem could be these two lines which don't specify a Workbook. Try: `Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(55)` and `Set NS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(56)`.

Comment: That did the trick @Ambie! Thanks!